# Keep data in page after refresh in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, angular-material, solution

when i open my website i will see "Finance/voucher" on top[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQks.png) but when i refresh the page only "Finance" Appears and i don't want this i want when i refresh page still it will show "Finance/voucher" And all relevant code i have posted plz guide me which code i enter and where

```
export class TopBarComponent extends AppComponentBase {

formName = ""
constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _formTitleService: FormTitleService,
 
) {
    super(injector);
  
}
ngOnInit() {
 
    this.getFormTitle();    
}
    getFormTitle(){
   
    this._formTitleService.getFormTitle()
        .subscribe(name => {
             
            this.formName = name; 
         
        });
    
}
Html code
<div class="page-title">
                / <span>{{formName}}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Well you are subscribing to "something" and setting the value to `formName`, so what is the issue? Please provide a  [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value for `formName = "Finance/voucher"` in your component & it will be retained on page refresh.

Comment: i can not do it  like this because formName variable store the value after "/" and there are  many more pages plz have a look at the code

Comment: you need to provide login info or more information about your question, according to the code you are setting `formName` from a service so it should be retained on load as the method will run again in ngOnInit. From where that initial value of `Finance/voucher` comes from when you load it the first time if not from service?

Comment: export class FormTitleService {

  constructor() { }

  formTitle= new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  setFormTitle(_formTitle: string) {
    debugger
    this.formTitle.next(_formTitle);
  }

  getFormTitle() {
    return this.formTitle;
  }
}   this is the services code  i am using only getFormTitle funcion from here

Comment: there are few issues with this, firstly you are subscribing directly to the `BehaviourSubject` you need to create a property with `formTitle.asObservable()` which should be subscribed in your component. It's hard to fix it & help in comment, try creating a demo of your code on jsfiddle or someplace else